# The name parametor does not exist in the current context in JQUERY method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have button and when It clicked  process event have been called and parameter passed to the event.

Here the code:

```
<input type="button" value="Accessing Layers" onclick="process('AccessingLayers');" />

 function process(actionName) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action(actionName)',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                sessionID: parent.parent.mapFrame.sessionId,
                mapName: parent.parent.mapFrame.mapName
            },
            success: function (result) {
                alert('Successfully passed data to controller');
            }
        });
    }
```

But in this row:

```
url: '@Url.Action(actionName)'
```

I get this error:

**The name 'actionName' does not exist in the current context**

Any idea why I get error above?

And how to fix it?

Comment: You are trying to mix server code and javascript. They run in completely different environments and at different times

Comment: @charlietfl, any idea how to change the code to make it work properly?

Comment: you need to concatenate a base url string with `actionName` in javascript so the end result points to correct url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember razor code executes on the server before the your client side code gets executed. So you cannot pass a javascript variable to a razor method like that.

If you still want to build the url using the Url.Action helper method and pass it to your process method, you should call the `Url.Action` method with correct arguments(the action method,controller name etc..) and generate the url and pass the url( generated by razor) to your javascript method as a string parameter value

```
<input type="button" value="Accessing Layers" 
                           onclick="process('@Url.Action("AccessingLayers")')" />
```

and your js code

```
function process(actionUrl) {
        $.ajax({
            url: actionUrl,
            // existing code
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="button" value="Accessing Layers" id="btnAccessingLayers" />
```

and in scripts section

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
           $('#btnAccessingLayers').on('click', function(){
                process('@Url.Action("AccessingLayers")');
                }
        });

        function process(actionUrl) {
        $.ajax({
            url: actionUrl,
            // existing code
        });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Everything typed between quotes is parsed as plain text, therefore no computation is performed on retrieving value of actionName.

You have to break your url like this:

url: '@Url.Action('+actionName+')'

so that actionName gets resolved as variable.

Comment: can't mix razor and javascript